# If condition is not working inside the script which uses a tempdata

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

The controller -

```
public ActionResult ChechUserNP(Login dd)
        {
            if (dd.userid == "admin" && dd.pwd == "admin")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "DataGridView");
            }

            else
            {
                TempData["Message1"] = 1;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }

        }
```

And this controller sends the `tempdata` to the view(html)

```
<script>
    debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        message = '@TempData["Message1"]';
        if (message !== null) {
            toastr.options = {
                "closeButton": true,
                "debug": false,
                "progressBar": true,
                "preventDuplicates": true,
                "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
                "onclick": null,
                "showDuration": "400",
                "hideDuration": "1000",
                "timeOut": "7000",
                "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
                "showEasing": "swing",
                "hideEasing": "linear",
                "showMethod": "fadeIn",
                "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
            }
            toastr.error('Username or Password is wrong')
        }
    });
</script>
```

If the userid or password is wrong it will return `TempData["Message1"] = 1;`.On the script it will check whether it has a value and if it does do the toastr. But what happens is when i load the page on the start the toastr works even if `if (message !== null)` is included.

So what i want is only to do the toastr when the `userid` or the `password` is wrong.
Whats wrong with my code,its for my school project

Comment: It appears you're interpolating the value into a Javascript string via some template system. It appears that the value will be a string in Javascript no matter what, at the very least it'll be `message = '';`. Which is not `null`…!? ‍♂️

Comment: Any solution for thats?

Comment: Check twice what your actual value will be in Javascript and adjust your test accordingly…? Or pass the value differently so it actually will be a Javascript `null`; how to do that we can't tell you for sure, not knowing what that template thing is.